# All pages leads me to index in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I've just migrated a wordpress site in nginx.

domain.com/loscabos/[wp-install]

WP is installed in "loscabos" folder
Thing is all my menu items leads to index inside domain.com

I guess it is a problem of .htaccess, but I don't how to fix it.

Here is my .htaccess ( inside wp-folder )

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /loscabos/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /loscabos/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have no .htaccess in domain.com folder

Any idea what's wrong??

Comment: mod_rewrite/htaccess is an Apache feature, for nginx configuration and rewrite rules, see this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Comment: uyyy ! Off course !!!! My migration was from apache to nginx

Comment: can u pass your site url